# Save the output of the time command to a log file

Tags: linux, shell, logging

I have a script hex.bat that has:

```
#!/bin/bash
HEX_ROOT=.
HEX_COLOURS=./data
HEX_PDB=.
HEX_MACROS=.
HEX_CACHE=./data

time ./hex6i.x64 -kill -nogui -ncpu 1 -ngpu 1 -e dock.mac -l job.log
```

All the output goes to `job.log`, except the time. I want to save in `jog.log` the time duration to execute this script. Does anyone have any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got using parenthesis

```
#!/bin/bash
HEX_ROOT=.
HEX_COLOURS=./data
HEX_PDB=.
HEX_MACROS=.
HEX_CACHE=./data

(time ./hex6i.x64 -kill -nogui -ncpu 1 -ngpu 1 -e dock.mac -l job.log) &> job.log
```

Comment: You should use "&>>" if you write the output to the same file as your actual command, otherwise the time output will overwrite the log from your command.

Answer (score 3):

`time` writes its output to standard errror, not standard output, so as to put the report in a different output stream.  It's common to want to time programs that are writing output to a file, for example, without putting the time output into the log.

If you do want the time output to go into the log, you have a couple of options:

1. Use the `-o` and possibly `-a` options of `time` to write the output of `time` to a log file.  Your `time` implementation may or may not have these options.
2. Redirect standard error: `time .... 2>> job.log` or `2>&1`.  The former writes to the same log file (via append); the latter sends the standard error output wherever the standard output would go.  Note that both will affect the program run by `time` as well as `time` itself.

Comment: Indeed, and intentionally so.  If you only care about the output from time, there's no point in redirecting standard output.  From the original question, the program being run apparently has its own management of logging and redirecting its standard output may not be desirable.  (There's a stray "as well" in my answer that may be confusing; I'll get rid of that.)

Comment: If you get the message `-o: command not found` - don't forget that `time` is a keyword in bash. You may need to use `command time` or `/usr/bin/time` instead - http://askubuntu.com/a/86196/227180